# I need help how do you break a loop without a dead code?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to do this loop but some reason when i put break i get a dead code

```
    if (Number % 2==0){ 

            System.out.println("Try again");

    } else 

    for (i = 0; i < number + 1; i++) { 
        for (j = number; j > i; j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (k = 0; k < (2 * i - 1); k++) {
            System.out.print(c);

        }
        System.out.println();
       break; 
      }
}
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The break makes no sense since it is unconditional (no if in front of it). So it will break out of the loop at the first iteration (i=0) which means you don't need a loop.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
public class random {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  int number = 5;
  int i, j, k;
  
  while (true) {
  
  System.out.println("Enter a number:  ");
  int Number = scan.nextInt(); 
  
  System.out.println("Which character you want to use:  ");
  char c = scan.next().charAt(0);

Comment: so im trying to create a program that will ask the user to enter a character and an odd number. You will then output a pyramid made of the user's given character. If the user enters an even number, ask the user to enter a number again until he/she gives a correct input.

Answer (score 0):

You always break out of the loop on the first iteration, so you never execute the `i++`.

If you remove that, it will compile.

However, that means you don't actually need a loop in the first place: a conditional would be equivalent:

```
if ((i = 0) < number + 1) {
    for (j = number; j > i; j--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (k = 0; k < (2 * i - 1); k++) {
        System.out.print(c);

    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```